# Tires stuck in the floors, what is the use?

Tags: dying-light

While playing I sometimes encounter tires half buried into the floor. Curiously mostly on buildings, or other places where you would not expect tires.

I can activate them to 'open'. But that does not seem to do anything.

It looks like this: 
[image: Tire with open prompt]

And this happens after activation:

[image: Tire sticking out of the ground]

(So, nothing, disregard the different location, 2 different screenshots)

Does anybody know what it does?

Comment: You can open tires? I don't remember anything like this (on PS4). Some sort of issue with the game's resource files?

Comment: Yeah i do not recall openable tires on the PC version either...

Comment: It only says 'open' on the action prompt. Does nothing.

More people found them, look over here: https://www.reddit.com/r/dyinglight/comments/37om2d/koreks_gasoline/ (around the deleted comments).

https://steamcommunity.com/app/239140/discussions/0/615085406657932366/ And over here are more people talking about it.

Comment: Added an image of the tire with the 'open' prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a bug](https://steamcommunity.com/app/239140/discussions/0/615086038679045451/) which turns normal, lootable containers into vehicle tires. This does not appear to be part of the [Korek Machete 2.0](https://dyinglight.fandom.com/wiki/Korek_Machete_2.0) Easter Egg weapon that uses obscure interactive items to retrieve.

As far as I can tell, these tires cannot be looted in the same way containers can be, but the prompt to interact with them still appears. This also explains why you see these strange tires in more than one location.

Comment: Of course, it being called bug on a Steam community forum is not conclusive proof, but there is no reason to assume it has another function. It also makes sense considering the size of both models and the presumed origin point, causing the tires to be submerged.